# Naive Bayes vs Neural Network

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to build a very straightforward bot that plays rock paper scissors against other bots (and has to win).

The features I have chosen are the previous moves by myself and the opponent (I created 3 nodes for each with a true/ false, so 6 nodes for previous moves) and whether or not I won last round. That makes 7 features in total as an input. <--- please let me know if I'm settings up my features correctly

Now these 7 features I have noticed can be related to each other such that the move last round and the win/loss can be combined to create another feature (eg. I lost + Opponent used rock = Opponent uses rock again). Which AI technique do you believe would capture this best? A Neural Network or Naive Bayes... or even another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing that is naive about Naive Bayes is that it assumes that features are independent. That is, it doesn't see "I lost and opponent used rock"; instead it sees "I lost", and also it sees "opponent used rock". "I lost" isn't useful to know on its own, and "opponent used rock" isn't either. So Naive Bayes isn't going to give you great results.

NNs would probably fit a bit better, but I think decision trees are probably your best bet here. As a bonus, you'll learn about decision trees, which are a much more useful AI technique to know than NNs.

Comment: `"... which are a much more useful AI technique ..."` - that's arguable.

Comment: I know. I just argued it. ;-)

Comment: Wow thanks for the quick response. Any suggestions on how I should set up the decision tree? Just to get me started

Answer (score 0):

I think NNs are a pretty good fit with this problem, actually. But I think you certainly need more inputs in order to have decent play: you need to model at least a handful of plays (i.e., "I played/they played" not just for one round but for the past `n` rounds, where `n` is at least, I dunno', 3 or 4).

You can argue whether you need a "I won the round" input or not: on the one hand, winning is emergent from the play, so you don't strictly need it, but "I played `x` and lost, so next time I'll play `y` or `z`" is a feasible pattern that would be easier to pick up if you *did* model win/lost.

The premise here is that there is a pattern sequence that can be detected (not just a statistical bias that the opponent plays `R` more often than `P` but that if they play `*PR*S` they often play `P` next). That strikes me as a reasonable hypothesis and it's the sort of pattern that you should be able to pick up with an NN.